# Linear Algebra - Adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

Preparing for an exam in Linear Algebra

I'm asked to show that $(f(T))^* = f(T^*)$ for any polynomial where $T^*$ is adjoint of a linear mapping $T$ and to deduce that $T$ and $T^*$ have same minimal polynomial.

Previously we have shown by induction that the adjoint of $T^n$ is $(T^*)^n$.

Comment: Your vector space is over the reals, I suppose, or the statement would be false.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

To answer the first question you should prove two points

- $( T^n)^*=(T^*)^n$ (already proved)
- $(T+U)^*=T^*+U^*$ :
  $$\langle (T+U)x,y\rangle=\langle Tx,y\rangle+\langle Ux,y\rangle=\langle x,T^*y\rangle+\langle x,U^*y\rangle=\langle x,(T^*+U^*)y\rangle$$
  for the second question notice by the previous question we see that any polynomial that annihilates $T$ annihilates also $T^*$ and conversely.

Comment: Don't see your point for the first question, second question i've done exactly as you said so good.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

For any scalar $\;r\in\Bbb C\;$ and any integer $\;k\;$, we have that

$$\begin{align*}(rT)^*&=\overline r\,T^*\\{}\\
(T^k)^*&=(T^*)^k\end{align*}$$